# Subscribe to form submit event from input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'd want to be able to use jQuery's `.on(event, function)` function to listen to form submission. For example, something like:

```
$("myInput").on("formSubmitted", functionToBeExecuted);
```

Seems pretty simple but yet I can't think of a solution (newbie backend dev here). Any ideas?

---

UPDATE:

Hmm seems like something else is going on with my code, `myInput.on('submit', functionToBeExecuted)` is not working for me and I don't see any errors in the console. There is nothing special but here's my code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {
    var input = $(containers[i]).find('[data-sf-role="text-field-input"]');

    if (input) {
        input.on('change', functionToBeExecuted);
        input.on('input', functionToBeExecuted);
        input.on('submit', functionToBeExecuted);
    }
}
```

The `change` and `input` event is working, only `submit` is not.

Comment: You mean `on("submit", functionToBeExecuted)`?

Comment: yes something like that

Comment: or was that an answer?

Comment: That was an answer.

Comment: can you post your html,css and js together in a code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Only The event name is the problem my friend, try this

```
$("myInput").on("submit", functionToBeExecuted)
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, but it doesn't seem to work for me, updated my question